# How to click on the Instagram Comment button using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, instagram

I'm basically trying to write a bot which comments on the most recent post of my timeline.
I have issues with finding the comment button using selenium.
I have tried every way of finding it but still didnt succeed.

HTML:

```
<svg aria-label="Kommentar" class="_8-yf5 " color="#262626" fill="#262626" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"><path d="M20.656 17.008a9.993 9.993 0 10-3.59 3.615L22 22z" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path></svg>
```

Code trials:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div\[5\]/div\[2\]/div/article/div\[3\]/section\[3\]/div/form/textarea').click()
```

Anyone can help me here?

Answer (score 1):

The click on the *Comment* button <kbd>Kommentar</kbd> within [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg[aria-label='Kommentar']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Kommentar']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

**Just use ENTER method:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

addComment = find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div\[5\]/div\[2\]/div/article/div\[3\]/section\[3\]/div/form/textarea')

addComment.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```